# php static class members not working

Tags: php, heredoc

I am stumped by the following code:

```
 <b><i>First name *</b></i> : <input type="text" 
                     name='<?php Labels::$FIRSTNAMELABEL ?>'  /><br />
```

This 'First Name' field is one of several inputs on a form on my page.
The Labels:$FIRSTNAMELABEL is set in the class definition to "FirstName".

Here is the class definition:

```
class Labels {
      static public $FIRSTNAMELABEL = "FirstName";
      // other static class members here for last name, phone #, etc.
      }
```

When the form appears in my browser I dump the page source and here's what I get:

```
<form action="AddPerson.php" method="post">
<b><i>First name *</b></i> : <input type="text" 
                     name=''  /><br />
```

You will notice that name=' ' is blank.  It **should** say name="FirstName" there in the page source.  Not be blank.

I have tried: single quotes, double quotes, spaces, no spaces around the php block, and inside the php block around the Labels::$FIRSTNAMELABEL -- no change.  When the form is displayed and I dump the page source, I always get name= (blank).

I discovered this with the following line of code:

```
  if( isset( $_POST[Labels::$FIRSTNAMELABEL])
```

The 'isset' always returns false, so I did a page dump and found out why -- when the form is submitted there IS no first name field called "FirstName" at all.

Funny thing about this is, I had this form inside a heredoc and it worked fine -- here's part of the form in my heredoc:

```
 <?php
  // this was successfully displaying a 'name=' field on the form set to the 
  // static class label called Labels::$FIRSTNAMELABEL -- ie. the 'name' field 
  // in the page source was name="FirstName"
 function showAddContactForm()
 {
     $firstNameLabel = Labels::$FIRSTNAMELABEL;
     // other field names not shown.....

     echo <<<_END
       <form action="AddContact.php" method="post">
       <b><i>First name *</b></i> : <input type="text" name=$firstNameLabel /><br />
      // other fields on the form not shown..
      </form>
 _END;
 }
 ?>
```

Why is my 'name=' field always blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a glance, there is no echo/print.

```
<b><i>First name *</b></i> : <input type="text" 
name='<?php echo Labels::$FIRSTNAMELABEL ?>'  /><br />
```

Comment: +1 and accepted -- thanks -- that did it.  I'm still learning about the echo, apparently. Been looking at this code and trying stuff for a long time today and echo'ing it out did not occur to me -- I guess the fact that the code I copied from the heredoc was working fine convinced me "the code worked before -- must be something else." thanks.